# Redirect custom post type from one domain to another domain

Tags: redirect, htaccess, seo, wp-redirect

There is a custom post type by the name of `code` parked on a domain: `sample.com`.
The redirect of the whole custom posts of `code` CPT to the custom posts of `code` CPT of `www.someanotherdomain.com`

`.htaccess` has such a capability?

Can we accomplish this? Is this a WP inbuilt feature?

URL Format:

`www.sample.com/code/how-php-works/` for example.

all post of that CPT to:

`www.someotherdomain.com/code/how-php-works/` for example.

Comment: Please include the URL format you are referring to. (btw `.htaccess` has 2 `c`s)

Comment: Includes, the URL format sir.

Comment: You want to redirect this particular post type..Right?

Comment: Is `someotherdomain.com` on a different server?

Comment: Yes, on completely different system/server.

Comment: You can use to ' Simple Website Redirect ' plugin  for redirect domain

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file at `sample.com`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^code/. https://www.someotherdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```